# Algorithm for picking orders from warehouses

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, knapsack-problem, traveling-salesman

I'll explain My Problem With an example.
Let's say we have:

- An **Order** from a certain store for **five** products, We will name those products **A,B,C,D,** & **E**, with their quantities In the **Order** *A(19),B(25),C(6),D(33),E(40)*.
- A single **Truck** that can fit different amount of each product:
  **A**(30), **B**(40), **C**(25), **D**(50), **E**(30).

*Ex*: Transporting **A** & **B** together, I loaded the the Truck with **A**(19) so that's two thirds of what my Truck can handle, So that leaves one third for **B**, Which means i can only transport 1/3 of **B**'s maximum Truck capacity which is (40/3 ≈ 13).

- A Set of **Warehouses** which contains different amounts of each product.

I made an Excel spreadsheet which contains more useful info regarding those Warehouses like( [Quantities](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w8scXbN-p8c95ZXN8LD4VMTQ-mBQuPvvjuQqkEoW1PQ/edit?usp=sharing), [Distance from Each other](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1knTRLSSY628pEygpOzj-kYZTacy5DQHAj7Rdx0PRT2E/edit#gid=0), [Distance from store](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RoRKiRWlUv5-4J4U6oWQvaoxtD9DSxK_gLBF1ulNVH8/edit?usp=sharing) ).

I want to Deliver this order to the store with the least amount of trips and distance traveled.

Is there an Algorithm for this kind of problem, Or something close i can modify on?

**EDIT:** Updated Links.

Comment: Sounds like a combination of Knapsack and Travelling Salesman...

Comment: Could you add the tables directly as text? Would make it easier for possible answerers than having to type all that in themselves.

Comment: How many stores are there?

Comment: Many stores, But the order must be delivered to the store that initiated the order

Comment: How many trucks are there? Only 1?

Comment: @Brainless like the stores there are many Trucks with different capacities, but only one can answer the order.

Comment: `with the least amount of trips and distance traveled` - one can imagine scenarios where these two constraints would be at odds, say if three stores relatively close to the target can combine to fulfill the order, but a single store further away also can.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError well its true, but in my case the order must be delivered to the store that ordered it,regardless of nearby stores.

Comment: Delivered, yes, but I am talking about pick-up.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Those links are Google docs, They won't die unless **I** deleted them or Google terminated them (which i will be notified of), And i only included theses link because they carry example data which i don't think can be displayed as wanted unless they where in a table, but thanks for notifying me, I'll try to include less unnecessary links in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise not to reinvent a wheel as a very first step of your work. Developing/adopting a custom algorithm for such a problem would be a very painful venture in my opinion. I would suggest using either *a constraint satisfaction programming (CSP) toolkit* or a direct *mixed integer programming (MIP) solver*.

My point is that it would be much easier to encode your problem using such tools. If performance/accuracy won't be enough for you - you could design a custom solution based on your preliminary results.

For CSP I would suggest [Minizinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) which has decent documentation and examples.

You could start your MIP research with [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/). It's not very powerful, but it's definitely capable of dealing with some toy examples.